# TextWrapping in DataGrid with ItemSource with collection of ExpandoObjects

Tags: wpf, xaml, gridview

I have some trouble getting my cells to Wrap, they just go out of bounds, when I look at the visual tree I can see that inside the contentpresenter it sees a text block which I try to set as a style on the content presenter, but when I look at the properties it says no wrap.

I don't know how to do it with a data template, cause its an list of expando objects that is bound to the gridview, where the dynamic properties is bound by the column name. So I don't see how I could bind text="{binding dynamicproperty}. Therefore I tried to change it on the content presenter.

```
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1">
        <DataGrid HeadersVisibility="None"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding SheetData}"
                  Background="Transparent"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  ColumnWidth="*"
                  IsHitTestVisible="False"
                  BorderThickness="0,2,0,0"
                  UseLayoutRounding="True"
                  BorderBrush="White"
                  RowBackground="Transparent"
                  MaxWidth="700"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                  HorizontalGridLinesBrush="White"
                  VerticalGridLinesBrush="White"
                  Behaviors:GridViewBindingBehavior.ColumnsCollection="{Binding ColumnData}"           
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                  Width="auto">
            <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Margin="5,0" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                   AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, 
                                  Path=Item.RowIndex}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>

            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8, 7"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />

                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#f1f2f4" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <ContentPresenter>
                                        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" >
                                                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Height" Value="auto"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                    </ContentPresenter>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>

        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Edit:
Since I don't think i am able to use a DataTemplate with the TextBlock within, due to the way i bind the columns, from my attached behavior, maybe there is a way to add the Text wrapping from code. I used the attached behavior from [here](http://www.nullskull.com/a/10476706/xaml-datagrid-binding-data-columns-or-rows-dynamically-using-mvvm-design-pattern.aspx).

Here is my attached behavior:

```
public class GridViewBindingBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsCollectionProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ColumnsCollection", typeof(ObservableCollection<DataGridColumns>), typeof(GridViewBindingBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(OnColumnsCollectionChanged));

    public static void SetColumnsCollection(DependencyObject o, ObservableCollection<ColumnDefinition> value)
    {
        o.SetValue(ColumnsCollectionProperty, value);
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<ColumnDefinition> GetColumnsCollection(DependencyObject o)
    {
        return o.GetValue(ColumnsCollectionProperty) as ObservableCollection<ColumnDefinition>;
    }

    private static void OnColumnsCollectionChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid gridView = o as DataGrid;

        if (gridView == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        gridView.Columns.Clear();

        if (gridView.ItemsSource == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        ObservableCollection<ExpandoObject> objExpando = (ObservableCollection<ExpandoObject>)gridView.ItemsSource;

        if (e.NewValue == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var collection = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<DataGridColumns>;

        if (collection == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        foreach (var column in collection)
        {
            var gridViewColumn = GetDataColumn(column);
            gridView.Columns.Add(gridViewColumn);
        }

    }

    private static DataGridTextColumn GetDataColumn(DataGridColumns columnName)
    {
        var column = new DataGridTextColumn();
        column.IsReadOnly = true;
        column.Header = columnName.DisplayColumnName;

        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Converter = new ColumnValueConverter();
        binding.ConverterParameter = columnName.BindingPropertyName;
        column.Binding = binding;

        return column;
    }
}
```

Edit 2:

I managed to get it to work with a value converter. The only thing is they way i find the actual row I am on is so ugly, is there a way to bind the datagrid to the second binding. I see the datagrid has CurrentColumn property, but i think that is for selections, and its null when inside the converter.

updated datagrid:

```
        <DataGrid HeadersVisibility="None"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding SheetData}"
                  Background="Transparent"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  ColumnWidth="*"
                  BorderThickness="0,2,0,0"
                  UseLayoutRounding="True"
                  BorderBrush="White"
                  RowBackground="Transparent"
                  MaxWidth="700"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                  HorizontalGridLinesBrush="White"
                  VerticalGridLinesBrush="White"
                  Behaviors:GridViewBindingBehavior.ColumnsCollection="{Binding ColumnData}"           
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                  Width="auto">
            <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Margin="5,0" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                   AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, 
                                  Path=Item.RowIndex}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>

            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8, 7"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#f1f2f4" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" >
                                        <TextBlock.Text>
                                            <MultiBinding  Converter="{StaticResource columnConver}">
                                                <Binding Path="." />
                                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}" Path="." />
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </TextBlock.Text>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>

        </DataGrid>
```

Ugly value converter:

```
public class ColumnMultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    private static int columnIndex = 0;
    private static int lastCount = 0;
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        var row = values[0] as IDictionary<string, object>;
        if (row == null)
            return row;

        var datagrid = values[1] as DataGrid;
        if (columnIndex >= datagrid.Columns.Count || lastCount != datagrid.Columns.Count)
            columnIndex = 0;

        var result = (row[datagrid.Columns[columnIndex].Header.ToString()]);
        columnIndex++;
        lastCount = datagrid.Columns.Count;
        return (result as GridCell)?.Value?.ToString();
    }
```

This maybe needs to be a new questions since the wrapping is done.
Just my code have become very ugly.

Comment: Not sure why the style isn't working, but have you tried setting the Wrap property directly in the DataTemplate TextBlock? Are the other style Properties working? Also, your target type is DataGridCell, should it not be TextBlock?

Comment: I tried, but i have bound expandoObjects, so the property binding on each column is dynamic. i tired to do a binding "." but it just give me the expandoObject and not the property.